# Is it possible to change `card` `width` of Google Chatbot?

Tags: javascript, chatbot, google-chat

I was looking around to change `card` `width` created by Google Chatbot but as far I see there is no any config within Chatbot API.

Is it possible to set an attribute somehow?

My current `Card` `class`;

```
class Card {
    constructor(title, subtitle, imgUrl) {
        this.sections = [];
        this.cardObject = {
            "cards": [
                {
                    "header": {"title": title, "subtitle": subtitle, "imageUrl": imgUrl},
                    "sections": this.sections
                }
            ]
        };
    }

}
```

and those are **Hangouts Chat API**s I've looked for now but no information about customise the `width` value;

- [Design guidelines](https://developers.google.com/hangouts/chat/concepts/ux#plain_text_vs_formatted_cards)
- [Card Formatting Messages](https://developers.google.com/hangouts/chat/reference/message-formats/cards)
- [Creating interactive cards](https://developers.google.com/hangouts/chat/how-tos/cards-onclick)

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, it is not possible to change the width of a card, per the broad [Cards](https://developers.google.com/hangouts/chat/reference/rest/v1/cards#section) overview.