# hangouts api cards trimming text

Tags: html, hangouts-api, google-hangouts

Im trying to send large descriptions inside a card using the google hangout api; but unfortunately the text is being trimmed when its too long.
Below is a sample of the card I send:

```
"cards": [{
        "sections": [{
                "widgets": [{
                        "keyValue": {
                            "topLabel": "Label",
                            "content": "Long Description goes here..."
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

When I look at the html received by the bot the content is in a dive with `white-space: nowrap;`...
I tried placing the content in a div and giving it `white-space: wrap;` as such 
`"content": "<div style='white-space: wrap;'>Long Description...</div>"`, but the bot just removes that div when it sends the card.

I also noticed that on pc browser the text was trimmed at 43 characters, so I used regex to add \n at every 43 character using `.replace(/.{42}/g, '$&\n')`, which kind of works but on mobile the card seems to trim messages even more...

Anyway I could simply remove that annoying `white-space` style??

**EDIT**

I know about [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56022932/is-it-possible-to-change-card-width-of-google-chatbot), but it tries to increase width of the card (which technically would work for me), and there were no solutions...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is possible to do it and very simple:

You only have to add `contentMultiline: true` to your `KeyValue` property.

```js
"cards": [{
        "sections": [{
                "widgets": [{
                        "keyValue": {
                            "topLabel": "Label",
                            "content": "The working day is thus not a constant, but a variable quantity. One of its parts, certainly, is determined by the working-time required for the reproduction of the labour-power of the labourer himself. But its total amount varies with the duration of the surplus labour. The working day is, therefore, determinable, but is, per se, indeterminate.",
                            "contentMultiline": true,
                        }
                     },
                 ]
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Here you'll find the documentation of `KeyValue` fields:

https://developers.google.com/hangouts/chat/reference/rest/v1/cards#keyvalue